# Azure DevOps - Pipelines Release view completely different, and broken. How can I set it back?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've recently started on a new project with a new firm. The release pipelines, in particular, the release view, is completely different, AND it doesn't work properly. The logs don't load, hardly any of the links work and it doesn't support themes correctly.

Does anyone know how to change it back? I've looked under preview for not only my user but the whole organisation and I don't know what is going on.

The first image is what I am after...

[image: Goodview]

This is what I currently have...

[image: Horrible]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have their account feature flags set to use the old release view. You can override that at the user level by going to "[Preview Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops)" and turning on "New release progress view".

Comment: Thank you so much, been struggling with this. What is amazing is that the "old" view is just completely broken now, it just doesn't work anymore.